# Java Android app. Loading all info from DB but only Display Certain ones

Tags: java, php, android, database

OK so for a while i have been getting "**names**" and "**location**" from the DB and listing them in a table.
one after an other using a loop until its all displayed there are 22 in all.

For example.

```
name 1 | location 1
name 2 | location 2 
name 3 | location 3
```

What i want to is no load the info in background as i already am but only pick the data when its needed, so i can have pictures txt then the data.

For example.

```
{Picture}                          {Picture}
{txt}{name 1}                      {txt}{name 2}
```

instead of it just all being listed one after another to make the page smarter looking. BTW this is a Results page for my Formula 1 app.

**GetDataFromDB2.java** ------

```
package com.test.test;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class GetDataFromDB2 {

public String getDataFromDB() {
    try {

        HttpPost httppost;
        HttpClient httpclient;
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://192.168.1.69/GetResults.php"); // change this to your URL.....
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                responseHandler);

        return response.trim();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
        return "error";
    }
}
}
```

This is the desplayed **Results.java**

```
package com.test.test;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.   graphics.   Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Results extends Activity {

String data = "";
TableLayout tl;
TableRow tr;
TextView label;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.results);

    tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

    final GetDataFromDB2 getdb = new GetDataFromDB2();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
            System.out.println(data);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<Users> users = parseJSON(data);
                    addData(users);                     
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}

public ArrayList<Users> parseJSON(String result) {
    ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Users user = new Users();
            user.setId(json_data.getInt("idresults"));
            user.setName(json_data.getString("driver"));
            user.setPlace(json_data.getString("local"));
            users.add(user);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
    }
    return users;
}


void addHeader(){
    /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
    tr = new TableRow(this);

    /** Creating a TextView1 to add to the row **/
    label = new TextView(this);
    label.setText("DRIVERS");
    label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    label.setPadding(20, 5, 5, 5);
    label.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 25, 25, 25));
    label.setTextColor(Color.argb(-19, 246, 255, 0));
    LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.addView(label,params);
    tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating textview2 Button **/
    TextView place = new TextView(this);
    place.setText("GRAND PRIX");
    place.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    place.setPadding(20, 5, 5, 5);
    place.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 25, 25, 25));
    place.setTextColor(Color.argb(-19, 246, 255, 0));
    Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.addView(place,params);
    tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

     // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
public void addData(ArrayList<Users> users) {

    addHeader();

    for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

        Users p = (Users) i.next();

        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText(p.getName());
        label.setId(p.getId());
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(20, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 25, 25, 25));
        label.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 198, 255));
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 1, 1, 0);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView place = new TextView(this);
        place.setText(p.getPlace());
        place.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        place.setPadding(20, 5, 5, 5);
        place.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 25, 25, 25));
        place.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 198, 255));
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 1, 1, 0);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(place,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

         // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
}
```

If you can figure it out you will see this Creates its own table and lays them out. 
all i want is to use the data at cirtain times in the page. ps each database entry as a "id" with them 
For example

```
ID - 1. name 1. location 1.   id - 2. name 2. locations 2  the id is just 1 - 22 would it be easyer using the id ?
```

Comment: how can i get a perticuler string or driver name from this . ps it has 22 names in it.      user.setName(json_data.getString("driver"));

Comment: fixed my problem by taking out the for loop and using Users p = users.get(1); to get the index number :D